# speech_recognition module python better on windows

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I am developing a voice assistant on a Raspberry pi, but I have noticed that the python script I have written produces much worse results on a pi than a windows pc using exact same mic and script. I have tried doing alsamixer on pi and turning up to no great success. the exact phrase that is most problematic is "hey GLaDOS" which transcribes perfectly on my pc but usually returns *"hey glass""8 lotto""hey Paris""Klaus"* or something equally far off on my pi. I am using a pi 2B with ethernet cable. the pi also perfectly transcribes from .wav files recorded using basic python script but just not using the stream in speech_recognition.

Please has anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this as i would like to run the system off the pi but it just isnt accurate enough for my purpose right now

the pi usually transcribes the word glados correctly on its own but when saying hey glados or ok glados it almost always gets it wrong unlike pc which gets it correct 9/10 times

i have speech recognition returning all possible transcriptions and if the most likely one is not "GLADOS", then none of the others are

some example code from my script:

```
def recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone):

    # check that recognizer and microphone arguments are appropriate type
    if not isinstance(recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
        raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")
    if not isinstance(microphone, sr.Microphone):
        raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")
    #sorting out adjustment for bg noise
    #from the microphone
    with microphone as source:
        recognizer.pause_threshold=1
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    #response object returns 3 parts - error message boolean for success and transcribed text if completed
    response = {
        "success": True,
        "error": None,
        "transcription": None                               #THIS FUNCTION WAS FOUND AT https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/
    }                                                       #as part of speech recognition library tutorial
    #try recognizing the speech in the recording
    #if a RequestError or UnknownValueError exception is caught,
    #update the response object accordingly
    try:
        response["transcription"] = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio, show_all=True))
    except sr.RequestError:
        # API was unreachable or unresponsive
        response["success"] = False
        response["error"] = "API unavailable"
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        # speech was unintelligible
        response["error"] = "Unable to recognize speech"
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #pygame audio init
    mixer.init()
    
    #recognizer and mic instances
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone = sr.Microphone()

    #with microphone as source:
    #    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

    #variables set before operation
    play_obj = None   
    song = 1
    active = False
    songactive = False

    while True:
        while True:
            command = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)
            if command["transcription"]:
                break
            if not command["success"]:
                break

        #if there was an error print it 
        if command["error"]:
            print("ERROR: {}".format(command["error"]))
            #break

        print(command["transcription"])

        #keyword listening
        if keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok GLaDOS") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok glass") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok ladders") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok Gladys") == True:
            active = True
            oneattempt = True
        
            while active == True:
                if oneattempt == False:
                    while True:
                        print("speak now")
                        command = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)
                        if command["transcription"]:
                            break
                        if not command["success"]:
                            break
                        print("I didn't catch that. What did you say?\n")

                    # if there was an error, stop 
                    if command["error"]:
                        print("ERROR: {}".format(command["error"]))
                        break

                print("You said: {}".format(command["transcription"]))

                #returns sound effect for when keyword activated or when user says hey glados again
                if keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok GLaDOS") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok glass") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok ladders") == True or keywordlocate(command["transcription"], "ok Gladys") == True:
                    vlines = ["hello again (low key).wav" , "hello again (high key).wav" , "lets get to business.wav"]
                    sound = mixer.Sound(random.choice(vlines))
                    sound.play()
                    while mixer.get_busy() == True:
                        continue
```

Comment: You should show some code. Also, the `speech_recognition` module supports multiple backends; it's possible that it's using a different backend on the RPi than on your Windows box.

Comment: i tried copying the ,init file for speech_recognition called it speech_recognition_mod then imported that and manually setting the samp rate and think it made a slight difference but  still not close to windows

Comment: The default sampling rate for SR microphones seems to be 16 khz, which might not be high enough for high fidelity recognition... Try turning that up? https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonedevice_index-unionint-none--none-sample_rate-int--16000-chunk_size-int--1024---microphone

Comment: keyword locate function just checks string within transcription

Comment: just going to try sample rate change thanks for that link

Comment: put samp rate up to 48khz seems to be better also it appears in more of the alternative lists so i can write a function to read them aswell#

Comment: Hi just another idea i had would running the same python program on windows iot on the pi make it run better?